# Applying EditText changes when another control is clicked

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Android activitity with a spinner, a few buttons, and an EditText control. I want to apply text changes when the user taps anything outside the text editor. To achieve this I tried to implement onFocusChanged() listener in the following way:

```
textEditor.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
       if(!hasFocus)
       {
          checkUpdatedText();
       }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, when I tap the spinner, the dropdown window appears, but the cursor is still visible in the text editor below it, and the onFocusChange() is not triggered. So the data in the dropdown list view is obsolete. Is there a way to ensure that the changes are applied exactly when another control is tapped? I do not want to update the data on every keypress, because this is a multiline edit view and the text may be lengthy.

Comment: Instead of handling it in onFocusChange, you can call checkUpdatedText() it in the onClick of all the other items like spinner, buttons etc.

Comment: @Azhar92 Thanks for the suggestion, I used onTouchListener() for the spinner, because it does not seem to support setting onClickListener().